# WebSync server on demand configuration problem

Tags: javascript, websync

I got a websync server on demand and registered a domain at www.hariwebsync.com and got the api key. In my javascript client , i wrote

```
  fm.websync.client.initialize({
    requestUrl: 'request.ashx',
    stream: {
        requestUrl: 'http://www.hariwebsync.com/request.ashx'
    },
    key: '1dee9f44-dc60-47f8-b544-ba9a466a6bae' 
});
```

to initialize the client. But, when i am loading the html file, i get an error "page not displayed". It is not able to load the registered domain (www.hariwebsync.com).

Can someone explain what i am doing wrong here. I am completely new to WebSync. So, please put up with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WebSync On-Demand, you don't need to specify any URLs:

```
fm.websync.client.init({
    key: '1dee9f44-dc60-47f8-b544-ba9a466a6bae' 
});
```

You should probably check out the Getting Started guide: http://docs.frozenmountain.com/#class=on-demand-getting-started-connecting-a-client